# Datatype 'long' (Int64) in COM InterOp

Tags: c#, web-services, vb6, interop

I'm making a proxy class in C# for VB6. The proxy is for a 3rd party webservice.
The webservice has properties defines as 'long' (Int64), which is not supported in VB6. I have defines extra 'object'-properties for each 'long'-property, which will be variant-type in VB6. Is this the right approach?

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IWSInterface
{
    [ComVisible(false)]
    long Value { get; set; }
    [DispId(1)]
    object Value_ { get; }
}
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class WSClass : IWSInterface
{
    //Interface is implemented in imported wsdl class (Reference.cs)

    object IWSInterface.Value_
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Changing to 'string' fixed the "problem", but had to change some autogenerated code.

Comment: How is `Long` not a supported type in VB?

Comment: ++Bob77.  @hightow, VB6 has the Long integer type.  Perhaps you're leaving out some details of the 'long' as defined by the webservice that are hampering your implementation?  How many bits? Signed or un-signed?

Comment: Sorry. 'long' defined by the WS is Int64. 'long' in VB is Int32.

Comment: So you need to pass an int64 to a VB6 COM DLL? VB6s Currency type is 64bit, although its scaled, or you could pass in a struct of hi/lo int32s, depends on what you want to do with 64bit values within the VB6 code.  If you don't need math, pass as string.